# got multi-item sequence

Tags: oracle, xmltable, oracle-xml-db

My intention is to "select the data where container number is equals to input data" (kind of search functionality). I am facing an issue when I am trying to retrieve the data, with a problem at where condition:

```
d:goodsShipments/d:consignment/d:transportEquipment/d:id/text()
```

Here I am getting multiple data. I don't know how to iterate it in the where condition.

My query is:

My source XML is:

How i can select all the declaration where sealId is 5678?
how deal with the where condition in this case?

Comment: Your sample XML is not complete or valid. You have `<ns:id>323</ns2:id>` with mismatched namespaces; `<ns2:tradeTerms>` without a closing tag; it doesn't have `declaration`, `localReferenceNumber`, etc.; other parts of your query don't seem to match the structure that is there. Kind of hard to interpret what you're doing with incorrect information.

Comment: Hi Alex,
added new xml which is taken from the Database

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer to use your sample; only real change is `/c:declaration` becomes `/d:declaration`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple containers per consignment, and you're filtering based on LRN after extracting that from the raw XML; so you need to use nested XMLTable objects. The first one gets the data from the declaration and extracts the consignments as a sub-XMLType. That is then passed to the second XMLTable which extracts the container information.

```sql
SELECT x1.lrn, x1.username, x2.containerNumber
FROM dmsimport_decl d
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.xxxx.invalid/xxxx/xxx/schema/xxx',
    'http://www.xxxx.invalid/xxx/schema/common' AS "c",
    'http://www.xxxx.invalid/xxxx/xxx/schema/xxx' AS "d"),
  '/d:declaration'
  PASSING d.object_value
  COLUMNS
    lrn VARCHAR2(35 CHAR)
      PATH 'c:declarationHeader/c:localReferenceNumber/text()',
    username CHAR(25)
      PATH 'c:declarationHeader/c:username/text()',
    consignment XMLType
      PATH 'd:goodsShipments/d:consignment'
) x1
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.xxxx.invalid/xxxx/xxx/schema/xxx',
    'http://www.xxxx.invalid/xxx/schema/common' AS "c",
    'http://www.xxxx.invalid/xxxx/xxx/schema/xxx' AS "d"),
  '//d:transportEquipment'
  PASSING x1.consignment
  COLUMNS
    containerNumber VARCHAR2(35 CHAR)
      PATH 'd:id/text()'
) x2
WHERE x1.lrn = 'NLDMS111111150010950';
```

With your (updated) sample XML, that produces:

```
LRN                                 USERNAME                  CONTAINERNUMBER                   
----------------------------------- ------------------------- -----------------------------------
NLDMS111111150010950                testSC testSC             abcd                               
NLDMS111111150010950                testSC testSC             bcde                               
NLDMS111111150010950                testSC testSC             cdef                               
NLDMS111111150010950                testSC testSC             defg                               
NLDMS111111150010950                testSC testSC             efgh
```

Hopefully that is what you want to see.

[Quick SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5268/1).

You could also use a more complicated XPath to keep it within a single XMLTable, but I think this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to iterate and get the id's from container component..

```
SELECT x1.lrn, x1.username, x2.containerNumber
FROM dmsimport_decl d
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.SSSSSSS/dmsimport',
    'http://www.SSSSSSScommon' AS "c",
    'http://www.SSSSSSSS/dmsimport' AS "d"),
  '/d:declaration'
  PASSING d.object_value
  COLUMNS
    lrn VARCHAR2(35 CHAR)
      PATH 'c:declarationHeader/c:localReferenceNumber/text()',
    username CHAR(25)
      PATH 'c:declarationHeader/c:username/text()',
    containerComponent XMLType
      PATH 'd:goodsShipments/d:goodsItems'
) x1.
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.SSSSSSSSS/dmsimport',
    'http://www.SSSSSS/common' AS "c",
    'http://www.SSSSSSSS/dmsimport' AS "d"),
  '//d:containerComponent'
  PASSING x1.containerComponent
  COLUMNS
    containerNumber VARCHAR2(35 CHAR)
      PATH 'd:id/text()'
) x2
WHERE x1.lrn = 'NL123456789160000464';
```