# Oracle 11.2.0.3 EXTRACT Value returns value of one node

Tags: xml, oracle11g, clob

I have an XML stored in a clob field. The xml has repeating nodes. My extract works when there are no repeating nodes (one submission with the clob). I am getting an error EXTRACT Value returns value of one node. What are my options considering my Oracle Version and the fact that the input field is of type CLOB on my Oracle table? I have tried XMLtable but have not been able to get it to work and I am not really sure that it can work with my data being stored in a clob.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE "LEAD_REPORTING_CLOB" 
("FILENAME" VARCHAR2(80),
 "SHARED_XML" CLOB);
```

My clob:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LeadReport xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile">
 <Lead>
   <AssociatedState>
   <StateOrCityCode>AZST</StateOrCityCode>
  </AssociatedState>
  <AssociatedState>
   <StateOrCityCode>MIST</StateOrCityCode>
  </AssociatedState>
  <PatternDescription>MI state</PatternDescription>
  <SourceIPAddress>
   <IPAddress>
    <IPv4AddressTxt>98.999.99.115</IPv4AddressTxt>
   </IPAddress>
   <IPTs>2016-04-25T10:12:19-07:00</IPTs>
  </SourceIPAddress>
  <SourceIPAddress>
   <IPAddress>
    <IPv4AddressTxt>192.888.888.888</IPv4AddressTxt>
   </IPAddress>
   <IPTs>2016-04-25T10:32:10-07:00</IPTs>
  </SourceIPAddress>
  <AdditionalInformation>
   <ReturnSubmStatus>U</ReturnSubmStatus>
    <EmailAddressDomain>emailchair.33xxxx.com</EmailAddressDomain>
   <PhoneNumberLastFour>5553</PhoneNumberLastFour>
  </AdditionalInformation>
 </Lead>
 <Lead>
  <AssociatedState>
   <StateOrCityCode>AZST</StateOrCityCode>
   </AssociatedState>
  <AssociatedState>
   <StateOrCityCode>MIST</StateOrCityCode>
  </AssociatedState>
  <PatternDescription>MI state2</PatternDescription>
  <SourceIPAddress>
   <IPAddress>
    <IPv4AddressTxt>98.444.44.444</IPv4AddressTxt>
   </IPAddress>
   <IPTs>2016-04-25T10:03:43-07:00</IPTs>
  </SourceIPAddress>
  <SourceIPAddress>
   <IPAddress>
    <IPv4AddressTxt>192.333.33.333</IPv4AddressTxt>
   </IPAddress>
   <IPTs>2016-04-25T10:20:33-07:00</IPTs>
  </SourceIPAddress>
  <AdditionalInformation>
   <ReturnSubmStatus>U</ReturnSubmStatus>
   <EmailAddressDomain>emailchair.33xxxx.com</EmailAddressDomain>
   <PhoneNumberLastFour>1744</PhoneNumberLastFour>
  </AdditionalInformation>
 </Lead>
 <Lead>
  <SubmissionId>9999988861170019999</SubmissionId>
  <AssociatedState>
   <StateOrCityCode>AZST</StateOrCityCode>
  </AssociatedState>
  <AssociatedState>
    <StateOrCityCode>MIST</StateOrCityCode>
  </AssociatedState>
  <PatternDescription>MI/AZ</PatternDescription>
  <SourceIPAddress>
   <IPAddress>
    <IPv4AddressTxt>98.222.22.222</IPv4AddressTxt>
   </IPAddress>
   <IPTs>2016-04-23T22:07:16-07:00</IPTs>
  </SourceIPAddress>
  <SourceIPAddress>
   <IPAddress>
    <IPv4AddressTxt>192.666.66.666</IPv4AddressTxt>
   </IPAddress>
   <IPTs>2016-04-25T21:59:21-07:00</IPTs>
  </SourceIPAddress>
  <SourceIPAddress>
   <IPAddress>
    <IPv4AddressTxt>198.111.111.111</IPv4AddressTxt>
   </IPAddress>
   <IPTs>2016-04-26T00:12:37-07:00</IPTs>
  </SourceIPAddress>
  <AdditionalInformation>
   <ReturnSubmStatus>R</ReturnSubmStatus>
   <EmailAddressDomain>emailchair.33xxxx.com</EmailAddressDomain>
   <PhoneNumberLastFour>0503</PhoneNumberLastFour>
   </AdditionalInformation>
 </Lead>
</LeadReport>
```

My Select:

```
select      
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead/SubmissionId',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "SubmissionId",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//StateSubmissionId',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "state_submission_id",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//StateOrCityCode',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "StateOrCityCode",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead/PatternDescription',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "PatternDescription",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//IPv4AddressTxt',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "IPv4AddressTxt",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//TCPPortNumber',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "TCPPortNumber",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//IPTs',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "IPTs",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//DeviceId',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "DeviceId",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//DeviceIdTs',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "DeviceIdTs",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//ReturnSubmStatus',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "ReturnSubmStatus",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//EFIN',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "EFIN",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//PTIN',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "PTIN",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//EmailAddressDomain',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "EmailAddressDomain",
          nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                    '//Lead//PhoneNumberLastFour',
                    'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
       '') as "PhoneNumberLastFour"

FROM 
   lead_reporting_clob ocr;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`extractvalue()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions061.htm#SQLRF06173) is deprecated anyway. And the `nvl()` call sin your code are redundant as you're replacing null with an empty string, which is the same as null in Oracle.

You can use [`XMLTable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB1700) to extract the information from multiple nodes:

```
select x.*
from lead_reporting_clob ocr
cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.xxx.yyy/efile'),
  '/LeadReport/Lead'
  passing xmltype(ocr.shared_xml)
  columns "SubmissionId" varchar2(20) path 'SubmissionId',
    "state_submission_id" varchar2(20) path 'AssociatedState/StateSubmissionId',
    "StateOrCityCode" varchar2(4) path 'AssociatedState/StateOrCityCode',
    "PatternDescription" varchar2(3) path 'PatternDescription',
    "IPv4AddressTxt" varchar2(15) path 'SourceIPAddress/IPAddress/IPv4AddressTxt',
    "TCPPortNumber" number path 'SourceIPAddress/TCPPortNumber',
    "IPTs" varchar2(25) path 'SourceIPAddress/IPTs',
    "DeviceId" varchar2(48) path 'SourceDeviceId/DeviceId',
    "DeviceIdTs" varchar2(25) path 'SourceDeviceId/DeviceIdTs',
    "ReturnSubmStatus" varchar2(1) path 'AdditionalInformation/ReturnSubmStatus',
    "EFIN" varchar2(10) path 'AdditionalInformation/EFIN',
    "PTIN" varchar2(10) path 'AdditionalInformation/PTIN',
    "EmailAddressDomain" varchar2(16) path 'AdditionalInformation/EmailAddressDomain',
    "PhoneNumberLastFour" varchar2(4) path 'AdditionalInformation/PhoneNumberLastFour'
) x;

SubmissionId         state_submission_id  Stat Pat IPv4AddressTxt  TCPPortNumber IPTs                      DeviceId                                         DeviceIdTs                R EFIN       PTIN       EmailAddressDoma Phon
-------------------- -------------------- ---- --- --------------- ------------- ------------------------- ------------------------------------------------ ------------------------- - ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----
530153999999zdhxxx                             OLF 999.99.99.999             443 2016-02-05T13:16:55-05:00 74B3A80AE5C68F2B65753C17XX59E5XX3779999A         2016-02-05T13:16:55-05:00 A 555555                GMAIL.COM        1899
9999992016108floxxx2 9999992016108xhaxxx2 GAST OLF 172.56.5.100              443 2016-04-17T08:07:54-04:00 6B9D4C4B0155EEE8FA30391BC8A012950009B366         2016-04-17T08:07:54-04:00 A 444444                YAHOO.COM        3822
```

You need to set the data type and size of each `columns` entry to match what you actually expect; I've approximated from the sample data.

---

With your updated example XML you have two repeating nodes under each lead, so you need to initially get them as their own XMLTypes, and then have further XMLTable calls to deconstruct them:

```
select xl."SubmissionId", xas."state_submission_id", xas."StateOrCityCode",
  xl."PatternDescription", xsi."IPv4AddressTxt", xsi."TCPPortNumber", xsi."IPTs",
  xl."DeviceId", xl."DeviceIdTs", xl."ReturnSubmStatus", xl."EFIN", xl."PTIN",
  xl."EmailAddressDomain", xl."PhoneNumberLastFour"
from lead_reporting_clob ocr
cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.xxx.yyy/efile'),
  '/LeadReport/Lead'
  passing xmltype(ocr.shared_xml)
  columns "SubmissionId" varchar2(20) path 'SubmissionId',
    associatedstate xmltype path 'AssociatedState',
    "PatternDescription" varchar2(10) path 'PatternDescription',
    sourceipaddress xmltype path 'SourceIPAddress',
    "DeviceId" varchar2(48) path 'SourceDeviceId/DeviceId',
    "DeviceIdTs" varchar2(25) path 'SourceDeviceId/DeviceIdTs',
    "ReturnSubmStatus" varchar2(1) path 'AdditionalInformation/ReturnSubmStatus',
    "EFIN" varchar2(10) path 'AdditionalInformation/EFIN',
    "PTIN" varchar2(10) path 'AdditionalInformation/PTIN',
    "EmailAddressDomain" varchar2(16) path 'AdditionalInformation/EmailAddressDomain',
    "PhoneNumberLastFour" varchar2(4) path 'AdditionalInformation/PhoneNumberLastFour'
) xl
cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.xxx.yyy/efile'),
  '/AssociatedState'
  passing xl.associatedstate
  columns "state_submission_id" varchar2(20) path 'StateSubmissionId',
    "StateOrCityCode" varchar2(4) path 'StateOrCityCode'
) xas
cross join xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.xxx.yyy/efile'),
  '/SourceIPAddress'
  passing xl.sourceipaddress
  columns "IPv4AddressTxt" varchar2(15) path 'IPAddress/IPv4AddressTxt',
    "TCPPortNumber" number path 'TCPPortNumber',
    "IPTs" varchar2(25) path 'IPTs'
) xsi;

SubmissionId         state_submission_id  Stat PatternDes IPv4AddressTxt  TCPPortNumber IPTs                      DeviceId                                         DeviceIdTs                R EFIN       PTIN       EmailAddressDoma Phon
-------------------- -------------------- ---- ---------- --------------- ------------- ------------------------- ------------------------------------------------ ------------------------- - ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----
                                          AZST MI state   98.999.99.115                 2016-04-25T10:12:19-07:00                                                                            U                       emailchair.33xxx 5553
                                          AZST MI state   192.888.888.888               2016-04-25T10:32:10-07:00                                                                            U                       emailchair.33xxx 5553
                                          MIST MI state   98.999.99.115                 2016-04-25T10:12:19-07:00                                                                            U                       emailchair.33xxx 5553
                                          MIST MI state   192.888.888.888               2016-04-25T10:32:10-07:00                                                                            U                       emailchair.33xxx 5553
                                          AZST MI state2  98.444.44.444                 2016-04-25T10:03:43-07:00                                                                            U                       emailchair.33xxx 1744
                                          AZST MI state2  192.333.33.333                2016-04-25T10:20:33-07:00                                                                            U                       emailchair.33xxx 1744
                                          MIST MI state2  98.444.44.444                 2016-04-25T10:03:43-07:00                                                                            U                       emailchair.33xxx 1744
                                          MIST MI state2  192.333.33.333                2016-04-25T10:20:33-07:00                                                                            U                       emailchair.33xxx 1744
9999988861170019999                       AZST MI/AZ      98.222.22.222                 2016-04-23T22:07:16-07:00                                                                            R                       emailchair.33xxx 0503
9999988861170019999                       AZST MI/AZ      192.666.66.666                2016-04-25T21:59:21-07:00                                                                            R                       emailchair.33xxx 0503
9999988861170019999                       AZST MI/AZ      198.111.111.111               2016-04-26T00:12:37-07:00                                                                            R                       emailchair.33xxx 0503
9999988861170019999                       MIST MI/AZ      98.222.22.222                 2016-04-23T22:07:16-07:00                                                                            R                       emailchair.33xxx 0503
9999988861170019999                       MIST MI/AZ      192.666.66.666                2016-04-25T21:59:21-07:00                                                                            R                       emailchair.33xxx 0503
9999988861170019999                       MIST MI/AZ      198.111.111.111               2016-04-26T00:12:37-07:00                                                                            R                       emailchair.33xxx 0503

 14 rows selected
```

The cross-joins turn this into more rows than you might be expecting; you can either combine things like the repeating IP (e.g. with listagg), or extract the repeating nodes into separate relational tables - it really depends what you intend to do with the results of your query.

Comment: That will do it. Thanks so much, Alex!

Comment: Now that I have loaded all of the data to the clob, I have tried the query and get the following error:   ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence

Comment: I tested it with the sample data you provided. Does your expanded CLOB have a lead node with multiples of one of the subnodes? If so you can have a second level of XMLTable but without an example it's hard to explain. [This example may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29942692/266304)?

Comment: I don't think there are duplicate nodes but possibly duplicate xml files. Would that have the same effect as duplicate nodes?

Comment: If there were multiple XML documents in the CLOB then the XMLType conversion would error first. There can only be a single top-level node (LeadReport). There must be something repeated further down, but without knowing the rules and structure it's hard to guess which (and could be several). The namespace `efile` doc might help you see which are allowed to be repeated. I'd guess you either have multiple `AdditionalInformation` nodes, or one of the values in that can be repeated - two email address domains, say; but none of it looks obviously repeatable..

Comment: I have updated the original question with an example from one of my problem files. It does contain duplicate nodes within the /lead node. Will a second level of XML table give me a separate record for each duplicated node? What if there are 3 of the same nodes within the /lead node? Will that require another xml table level?

Comment: @Marianne - three of the same node would be OK; but you have more than one node that repeats so you need a separate sub-XMLTable for each of those. And the cross-join of them all might give you more data than you wanted. It depends what you plan to do with the extracted data though - if you're going to store it relationally you can put the repeating nodes (at least) into separate tables.

Comment: Thanks so much, Alex. I'm not really sure why we have repeating nodes at all but it will be up to the business to figure out what to do with that.